# Guest machine using all the RAM allocated to it

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, kvm, virtual-memory

I have installed KVM on my host machine (Linux). and I created a guest machine (Windows) on it.

I have assigned 16GB RAM to the guest machine. so on the host machine, it shows 16GB RAM utilized. even if the guest machine is idle.

I tried KSM service to resolve it. but it didn't work.

Comment: Using for example top, does it show 16GB RES (~ physical) or VIRT (virtual)?

Comment: I deleted VM with 16GB RAM and created VPS with 2GB RAM. It is shows 2.1g under RES in top command.

Comment: Ok. so it's really used (well there might have been a difference when it was 16 rather than 2). Meaning I don't have any idea to help. Ah yes: install virtio drivers for memory balloon handling: https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers/Download_Drivers